# Avoid instantiations inside loops Angular

Tags: angular

I have these lines of code that has bug with cast green software scaning.

```
   public addFilesToQueue(files: FileList | any): void {

        const addedFiles: AttachmentItem[] = [];

        for (let iFileId = 0; iFileId < files.length; iFileId++) {

            const file = files.item(iFileId);

            const attachment: AttachmentItem = new AttachmentItem(uuid(), file);
            
            if (!attachment || !attachment.file) {
                return;
            }

            this.attachments.push(attachment);
        }

        this.messageBusService
            .addMessage<AttachmentItem[]>(WebMessageBusChannelNameConstant.attachmentTableListFile, WebMessageBusEventNameConstant.updateAttachmentTableListFile, this.attachments);
       
        for (const availableFile of this.attachments) {
            this.buildUploadRequest(availableFile).pipe(
                switchMap((httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>) => {
                    return this.httpClient
                        .request(httpRequest);
                }),
                map(httpEvent => {
                    return availableFile;
                })
            ).subscribe();
        }
    }
```

The line that cause the error is:
const attachment: AttachmentItem = new AttachmentItem(uuid(), file);
Here is the AttachmentItem:

```
 export declare class AttachmentItem {
    id: string;
    fileName: string;
    fileType: string;
    referenceType: string;
    referenceId: string;
    documentType: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    updatedBy: string;
    file: File;
    status: AttachmentItemUploadStatuses;
    private _progress;
    private _canceller;
    progress: number;
    readonly canceller: Subject<boolean>;
    constructor(id: string, file: File);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its strange, but I guess its just trying to optimize your code, generally we can workaround this error, by using other methods of iteration like `map`. so I converted the for loops to `map` and added a `forkJoin` for your observables, this will save all the uploaded files parallelly!

---

Instead of instantiating a class, we can just create an object containing just the important properties, this will save memory!

```
public addFilesToQueue(files: FileList | any): void {
    this.attachments = Array.from(files) //convert to array
    .map((file: File): AttachmentItem =>  
         ({
              id: uuid(), 
              file: file,
              // add any other properties if needed!
         })) // use a map to do the same as for loop!
    .filter((attachment: AttachmentItem) => !attachment || !attachment.file); // filter the unwanted values

    this.messageBusService.addMessage<AttachmentItem[]>(
      WebMessageBusChannelNameConstant.attachmentTableListFile,
      WebMessageBusEventNameConstant.updateAttachmentTableListFile,
      this.attachments
    );
    // below code creates an array of observables, to enable parallel save of files 
    const bulkUploadArray$ = this.attachments.map((availableFile: AttachmentItem) => this.buildUploadRequest(availableFile).pipe(
      switchMap((httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>) => {
        return this.httpClient.request(httpRequest);
      }),
      map((httpEvent) => {
        return availableFile;
      })
    ));
    // triggers the parallel save!
    forkJoin(bulkUploadArray$).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this gonna work because we need to avoid instatiation inside loop. Is there another way to it

Comment: @Thanh share the contents of `AttachmentItem`

Comment: I added the contents